# Как сделать в java, если введенный номер в EditText содержит меньше или больше 12 символов то выдавало "Некорректный телефон"?

Tags: java, android

```
    if (editTextPhone.) {
        editTextPhone.setError("Некорректный телефон");
        editTextPhone.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: проверять длину

Comment: в xml файле android:maxLength="12"

Comment: или через Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/14433261/9057721

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить строку:

```
String phoneStr = editTextPhone.getText().toString();
```

Измерить длину:

```
int len = phoneStr.length();
```

Проверить:

```
if(len != 12){
    editTextPhone.setError("Некорректный телефон");
    editTextPhone.requestFocus();
    return;
}
```